# Some text to be bold after every line break after using nl2br

Tags: php, html-entities, nl2br

I am fetching data from one field called PostContent from mysql DB and using nl2br which comes as line break. i have succeeded to fetch the nl2br but i want some text to be bold after every line break.

in Database i have stored as longtext for postContent i want output as follows:

**Dimensions:**

```
Height: 134.7 mm
Width: 68.5 mm
```

**Display and User Interface:**

```
Display size: 11.94 cm
```

**Keys and Input Methods:**

```
some text
some more text
```

---

i am geting like:

```
Dimensions:
Height: 134.7 mm
Width: 68.5 mm

Display and User Interface:
Display size: 11.94 cm

Key Features: Should be Bold</B>
some text
some text
```

the code is:

```
$url=$_GET['url'];
$sql ="SELECT * , DATE_FORMAT( postDate,  '%d %b %Y' ) postDate FROM posts where url ='$url'";
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$postContent=nl2br($row['postContent']);
?>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p><?php echo"$postContent.";?></p>
                </div>
<?php
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: You must study regex and use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: @ the_nuts i am just a beginner of php

Comment: Can we see the code that displays the text?  I have a feeling that you could modify your template or output to bold the text without any sophisticated techniques.

Comment: @SurrealDreams i have added the code above, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank everyone for their kind support.
i got solution for my question so thought of sharing the same, With the help of tinymce and html_entity_decode now i am able to get the desired output. actually i am inserting the html tags in database with the help of HTML WYSIWYG called tinymce and rendeting the same using html_entity_decode.
now using following code i can insert any html tag and render the same using html_entity_decode  without rendering the html tags.

```
$url=$_GET['url'];
$sql ="SELECT * , DATE_FORMAT( postDate,  '%d %b %Y' ) postDate FROM posts where url ='$url'";
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$postContent=nl2br($row['postContent']);
$content=html_entity_decode($postContent);
?>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p><?php echo"$content.";?></p>
                </div>
<?php
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a change to split the headers out. However, I dp not see a way to easily put the dimensions each on a separate line. Run this and see if you can live with it. It should at least get oyu close to what you want.

```
<?php
$url=$_GET['url'];
$sql ="SELECT * , DATE_FORMAT( postDate,  '%d %b %Y' ) postDate FROM posts where url ='$url'";
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$postContent=nl2br($row['postContent']);
$mydata = explode(chr(10), $postContent);

foreach($mydata as $value)
{
  echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
 echo "<p><strong>".substr($value,0,strpos($value, ':')+1)."</strong></p><p>".substr($value,strpos($value, ':')+2);
echo "</div>";
}
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: @ Len_D fieldname i have as only one called  postContent and all the paragraph coming from there.

Comment: Ah, so there could be several strings with colons. I see. let we look at that.

Comment: How is postContent stored in your table? Is it a text field? Is the data stored one line each, or all together,? I'm trying to figure out how the actual data looks when it's in $row['postContent']. Can you show that?

Comment: its it stored like textfield as longtext and it looks like as shown on top for example: Dimensions: Height: 134.7 mm Width: 68.5 mm

Comment: no luck, and also "Dimensions: Height: 134.7 mm Width: 68.5 mm
Display and User Interface: Display size: 11.94 cm
Key Features: some text some text some text" is coming from postcontent only

Comment: its not exactly as i want but almost nearby. may be i am not able to explain what i want really because of i am just a beginner in php. Thanks Len_D, you can see the example after integrating your suggestion @ http://www.egadgetsworld.com/Sony-Xperia-E3-Dual

Comment: So what does "not exactly as I want" mean? What isn't displaying the way you want it to?

Comment: Plesae have a look on top once again may be this time i have explained it if i am not wrong.

Comment: OK. that layout is different than what you originally posted. I'll take a lok at it.